# Unable to filter ACL.IdentityReference to exclude certain pattern?

Tags: regex, powershell, active-directory

The below script is working fine to list all explicitly defined ACL in my file server directories. However, I need to exclude the below Object and SID:

> ```
> 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM',
> 'BUILTIN\Administrators',
> 'CREATOR OWNER',
> 'Everyone',
> 'DOMAIN\SERVICE-AVScan,
> 'S-1-5-21'
> ```

In the below code I need to exclude any entries with the above pattern.  This is my code so far.

```
$Excludes = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'BUILTIN\Administrators', 'CREATOR OWNER', 'Everyone', 'S-1-5-21'
$reExcludeObjects = '^({0})$' -f (($Excludes | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')

function Get-CustomDirInfo([IO.DirectoryInfo]$path, $parentAcl)
{
    $containerInherit = [Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit
    $acl = (Get-Acl -Path $path.FullName).Access | Foreach-Object {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Path = $path.FullName;
            IdentityReference = $_.IdentityReference;
            FileSystemRights = $_.FileSystemRights;
            IsInherited = $_.IsInherited;
            InheritanceFlags = $_.InheritanceFlags;
            InheritedFrom = if ($_.IsInherited)
            {
                if ($parentAcl)
                {
                    $current = $_
                    $parentAce = $parentAcl.Access | Where-Object {
                        ($current.IdentityReference -eq $_.IdentityReference) -and
                        ($current.FileSystemRights -band $_.FileSystemRights) -and
                        ($_.InheritanceFlags -band $containerInherit) -and
                        ($_.IdentityReference -notmatch $reExcludeObjects)
                    }
                    if (!$parentAce -or ($parentAce.count -gt 1))
                    {
                        Write-Warning "Something is not right Parent ACE Count = $($parentAce.count) - $($path.FullName)"
                        #Export the broken direcotries path as unique entries 
                        $BrokenACLDirectories += $path.FullName
                        $BrokenACLDirectories | Select-Object -exp FullName -Unique | OGV -Title "There are $($BrokenACLDirectories.Count) Broken Directories"
                    }
                    if ($parentAce.IsInherited)
                    {
                        $parentAce.InheritedFrom
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Split-Path $path.FullName -Parent
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    "Unknown (Top:$($path.FullName))"
                }
            }
            else {
                "Not Inherited"
            }
        }
    }
    
    $acl
    $inheritableAcl = $acl | Where-Object { $_.InheritanceFlags -band $containerInherit }
    $path.FullName | Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer } | Foreach-Object { Get-CustomDirInfo $_ $inheritableAcl }
}

Get-CustomDirInfo (Get-Item C:\Users\Public) | ft Path, IdentityReference, FileSystemRights, IsInherited, InheritedFrom -Auto
```

This is the error in my IDE:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/uWtUOWC.png]

This is the section of the code I am stuck on:

```
Where-Object {
               ($current.IdentityReference -eq $_.IdentityReference) -and
               ($current.FileSystemRights -band $_.FileSystemRights) -and
               ($_.InheritanceFlags -band $containerInherit) -and
               ($_.IdentityReference -notcontains $ExcludePattern )
             }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the regex `-notmatch` operator with `($_.IdentityReference -notmatch $reExcludeObJects)`, you need to escape the strings in the exclude array before you join them with `|`

```
$Excludes = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'BUILTIN\Administrators', 'CREATOR OWNER', 
            'DOMAIN\SERVICE-AVScan', 'Everyone', 'S-1-5-21'
$reExcludeObjects  = '^({0})' -f (($Excludes | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')

$parentAce = $parentAcl.Access | Where-Object {
    ...
    ($_.IdentityReference -notmatch $reExcludeObjects)
    ...
}
```

If you want to use `-notcontains`, then use the $Exclude array as-is, like in [Doug Maurer's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63878031/9898643)

```
$Excludes = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'BUILTIN\Administrators', 'CREATOR OWNER', 
            'DOMAIN\SERVICE-AVScan', 'Everyone', 'S-1-5-21'

$parentAce = $parentAcl.Access | Where-Object {
    ...
    ($Excludes -notcontains $_.IdentityReference)
    ...
}
```

Also, I would prefer to create the $Exclude array (and if you use `-notmatch` also the $reExcludeObjects regex string) **inside** the function, or send it to the function as a new parameter, but that's up to you.

Comment: thank you for the update, however, when I executed the script using both of the methods you've suggested, the unwanted ACL objects are still exist, or the same as it was before?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Ah, the `IdentityReference` property is part if the `.Access` property of the ACL object. Changed the code.

Comment: it is still showing the 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM',
'BUILTIN\Administrators',
'CREATOR OWNER', object? I have updated the code as suggested.

Comment: Since you seemed to have added information to the IdentityReference, try Theo's recommendation but remove the $ which indicates the end of the line. Change the line to `$reExcludeObjects  = '^({0})' -f (($Excludes | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')` and use the `-notmatch` since it would strictly be a regex match. Neither `-notin` nor `-notcontains` will work since the full line includes more than the identity.

Comment: @DougMaurer yes, it is now working as expected :-) many thanks.

Comment: @Theo, many thanks for your support and the sharing in this community, it is work without the $ sign on the RegEx pattern.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Thanks for letting us know. The `$` anchor in the regex is indeed unwanted (I've taken it out in the answer for clarity). Thanks for this to @DougMaurer who spotted it.

Comment: @Theo No problem man, I appreciate your assistance in this community.

Answer (score 1):

I would make it less complicated, stick with your original $excludepattern and use -notcontains or -notin

```
$ExcludePattern = @(
    'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM',
    'BUILTIN\Administrators',
    'CREATOR OWNER',
    'DOMAIN\SERVICE-AVScan',
    'Everyone',
    'S-1-5-21'
)

(Get-Acl $item).Access | where IdentityReference -notin $ExcludePattern
```

or

```
$ExcludePattern = @(
    'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM',
    'BUILTIN\Administrators',
    'CREATOR OWNER',
    'DOMAIN\SERVICE-AVScan',
    'Everyone',
    'S-1-5-21'
)

(Get-Acl $item).Access | where {$ExcludePattern -notcontains $_.IdentityReference}
```

Edit:

As I commented, your function is quite convoluted. Let's keep it to minimal reproducible example.

For these examples, I will use the c:\windows\system32 directory.

```
$item = 'c:\windows\system32'
```

Now normally I see

```
(Get-Acl $item).Access | select identityreference

IdentityReference                                                
-----------------                                                
CREATOR OWNER                                                    
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                              
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                              
BUILTIN\Administrators                                           
BUILTIN\Administrators                                           
BUILTIN\Users                                                    
BUILTIN\Users                                                    
NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller                                      
NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller                                      
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES           
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES           
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES
```

Then the list is limited to this after the `ContainerInherit` filtering

```
$containerInherit = [Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit
(Get-Acl $item).Access | where {$_.InheritanceFlags -band $containerInherit} | select identityreference

IdentityReference                                                
-----------------                                                
CREATOR OWNER                                                    
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                              
BUILTIN\Administrators                                           
BUILTIN\Users                                                    
NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller                                      
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES           
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES
```

And finally, when combined with your exclusion list.

```
(Get-Acl $item).Access | where {$_.InheritanceFlags -band $containerInherit} | where IdentityReference -notin $ExcludePattern | select identityreference
```

or

```
(Get-Acl $item).Access | where {$_.InheritanceFlags -band $containerInherit -and $_.IdentityReference -notin $ExcludePattern} | select identityreference
```

both produce

```
IdentityReference                                                
-----------------                                                
BUILTIN\Users                                                    
NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller                                      
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES           
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES
```

As the test clearly shows, Creator Owner, NT Authority\SYSTEM, and BUILTIN\Administrators are all removed. The same is true with the alternative `-notcontains`

```
(Get-Acl $item).Access | where {$_.InheritanceFlags -band $containerInherit -and $ExcludePattern -notcontains $_.IdentityReference} | select identityreference

IdentityReference                                                
-----------------                                                
BUILTIN\Users                                                    
NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller                                      
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES           
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES
```

If you are seeing different results in your function, I recommend breaking it down into smaller sections to debug.

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks for the update. However, even after changing it into: ($_.IdentityReference -notin $ExcludePattern )
The unwanted pattern still showed?

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? Your function is too convoluted. My example with your list will exclude system and administrators

Comment: Already, updated as above, when you execute the script on your file server or any of your local server file structure, you can safely run it to check the result.

Comment: Hi @Doug, the results are still the same, the unwanted objects are still showing?

Comment: with the updated code, the system32 directory give me this error: WARNING: Something is not right Parent ACE Count = 0 - C:\windows\system32\spool\V4Dirs\CA3863DE-C622-4474-B0E6-1BE3D31E07EE

Comment: Is this section is correct when using RE ?
$parentAce = $parentAcl.Access | Where-Object {
 ($current.IdentityReference -eq $_.IdentityReference) -and
 ($current.FileSystemRights -band $_.FileSystemRights) -and
 ($_.InheritanceFlags -band $containerInherit) -and
 ($_.IdentityReference -notmatch $reExcludeObjects)
}

Comment: You don't need those parentheses in this example. Other than that, it seems fine.

Comment: I have also updated the post, with my screenshot, it is still showing the 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM',
'BUILTIN\Administrators',
'CREATOR OWNER', ?

Comment: Thank you for the update man, your post is very informative.
I appreciate your assistance in this matter.